# I mistakenly deleted most of my files with Git, is there a way to recover?

Tags: git, github, backup, restore

I was attempting to update a GitHub repository from the command line and now most of my files are gone. I used VSCode and opened up the folder, "2022 Portfolio" containing my project, and ran some commands from a terminal in VSCode.

I followed a video from YouTube to upload my code to GitHub using the command line. I followed what I believe are the usual commands and I think the last command I ran before I got myself into trouble was: `git push -u origin main To https://github.com/matthewlieb/2022-portfolio.git`

This returned the following `error: error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/matthewlieb/2022-portfolio.git'`

After this, I turned to ChatGPT for help and I think this is where I got in trouble. I have the entire conversation, but the commands I ran after a back-and-forth with the chatbot (which included errors leading to the next command) were as follows:

```
git push origin main
git config pull.rebase false
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories origin main
```

Now, all my files are missing. I don't know how to restore a backup or what to do. Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated and I can provide any additional information as needed.

Comment: I wonder how it thought that the niche `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories origin main` would be a nice thing to run in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Please, don't start wood working with this approach :)

Good news everyone! It is really hard to actually lose files with git. As a first reflex, turn to [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog): it will list all the previous stages you've locally been to.
Example:

```
$ git reflog
341b480 (HEAD -> feature/49-uninstall-script, origin/feature/49-uninstall-script) HEAD@{0}: commit: fixup! fix authelia rsa command
353f80e HEAD@{1}: commit: fix authelia rsa command
3a79235 HEAD@{2}: commit: fixup! unrelated fix: sync authelia version
e951e1f HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from develop to feature/49-uninstall-script
0e39f52 (origin/develop, origin/HEAD, develop) HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from feature/49-uninstall-script to develop
```

From this local history, find one that looks promising and check it out:

```
$ git checkout HEAD@{42}
```

From there, you have a working directory in a proper state. Now would be the good time to learn how to use git as to properly push this local state to origin.

Comment: Thanks for the help and good advice. I think I have learned my lesson. But, I still can't figure out how to recover my files. I run `git reflog` and get:

```660e5c9 (HEAD, main) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from main to 660e5c9e56f46c2ab9b7daed1a236e7d55faa10c
660e5c9 (HEAD, main) HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from 660e5c9e56f46c2ab9b7daed1a236e7d55faa10c to main
660e5c9 (HEAD, main) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from main to 660e5c9e56f46c2ab9b7daed1a236e7d55faa10c`
```

Tried each one with `git checkout HEAD@{}`, but the files don't show up. A couple folders say 'waiting to upload'.

Comment: FWIW, it's a lot of my work that is missing so I will gladly pay for help to recover these files or for tutoring with git :)

Comment: Beware, each time you checkout a ref, the reflog list shifts by one. You might have checkouted the same working directory multiple times.

Comment: If I checkouted the same working directory multiple times, is there a way to undo that? I am not sure what that means.

Comment: I also want to clarify, all of my files are gone from my Desktop, Documents, etc. Not just files from a git repo. I am not sure if this is actually the result of a git problem or some other error.

Comment: I cannot help you without more information. You should edit your question with a significant part of `git reflog`.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you did `git pull`, you handled the conflicts incorrectly, causing the remote repository's content to overwrite the local repository.

You should use the `git log` command to check your last commit, and then use `git checkout commitid` to restore it.

If you are a beginner and don't want to deal with conflicts, you can use `git push -f` to force the local repository to overwrite the remote repository.

This is a simple approach, but I think you should learn how to handle git conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried `git log` and I get the following:

`matthewlieb@matthewlieb 2022 Web Portfolio % git log
commit 660e5c9e56f46c2ab9b7daed1a236e7d55faa10c (HEAD, main)` 

Then, I did `git checkout commitid` but I get this:
`matthewlieb@matthewlieb 2022 Web Portfolio % git checkout commitid
error: pathspec 'commitid' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Any thoughts? I will definitely figure out how to properly use git going forward and handle git conflicts but right now, I am panicking.

Comment: Commit ID is the hash value you get from the `git log` command, like '660e5c9e56f46c2ab9b7daed1a236e7d55faa10c'. If you do `git checkout 660e5c9e56f46c2ab9b7daed1a236e7d55faa10c`, you should be able to restore your code to the state it was in when you made that commit. I hope you made a commit before losing your code, otherwise it might be tough to get it back.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried this with the hash value I got and it didn't restore my files. It is most of my files that are missing, not just code that I was trying to push.

Answer (score 0):

> I also want to clarify, all of my files are gone from my Desktop, Documents, etc. Not just files from a git repo.

That should not happen, unless you had a Git repository (a hidden .git folder directly in `%USERPROFILE%` (`C:\Users\yourLogin`)

If that is the case, then try the git reflog command from the actual root of the Git repository (`%USERPROFILE%`), and use `git reset --hard -- anOldSHA` to try and restore files, assuming they were committed in said Git respository.

Comment: Thanks! When I try `git reflog` in `C:\Users\myLogin` I get the following:
`fatal: your current branch 'main' does not have any commits yet`

Could this mean I had a Git repository in my `%USERPROFILE%` but didn't commit the files? Would it be possible to commit and then to recover the files using `git reset --hard -- anOldSHA`? 

What is interesting is some files remain, like the files in the actual directory that I was trying to upload to GitHub. However, all of my other files in my iCloud have disappeared. The folders also remain but they are all empty.

Comment: Another note I'd add is I have a couple of folders that say that 'Waiting to upload' I am not sure what is waiting to upload, maybe it is all of my files that have vanished?

Comment: @mattyicebear iCloud? So you should be able to [recover files from iCloud](https://support.apple.com/en-my/guide/icloud/mmae56ea1ca5/icloud).

Comment: @mattyicebear For the "Waiting to upload", see [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/qkv8l9/folder_is_indefinitely_stuck_in_waiting_to_upload/).

Comment: Thank you! I am able to recover files from iCloud. That also takes care of the "Waiting to upload". I was not aware of the iCloud recovery and assumed the files were deleted through Git. I am still not sure what caused the files to be deleted. I appreciate the help!